# help with database design for discord bot

Tags: database-design, schema

I'm a beginner. I'm building a discord bot and i need help with database design for plugins/subplugins. the [structure](https://lucid.app/lucidchart/6651024a-15fe-4167-9e2a-3166c7fe1683/edit?viewport_loc=-1678%2C-190%2C3040%2C1555%2C0_0&invitationId=inv_49d06a57-6a94-40af-8338-732001e490fe) i have thought of.

a plugin may or may not have configs, subplugins or values.

---

example of plugin with only values:

- auto_message: each value is defines a message to send at X interval

---

example of plugin with only configs:

- welcome: config stores the message to send and the channel to send it when a member joins a server

---

example of plugin with subpluggins:

moderation

├── lockdown

├── mute_ban

├── appeals

---

configs holds like the settings or general parameters. while values, if applicable, holds one 'instance' of the functionality of plugin.

feedback please

[image]